# access base class field from derived&&subclass

Tags: c#, class, subclass, radix, derived

I can't understand why I have access to Base class's field. I have no object of Base class, and private fields are not inherited as I know. When I try to get field "i" of class "SubDerived" with reflection, it cannot find it. please anyone explain..

```
using System;

    namespace tests
    {
        public class Test
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Base.SubDerived a = new Base.SubDerived();
                a.f();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        class Base
        {
            int i = 1;

            public class SubDerived : Base
            {
                public void f()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(base.i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SubDerived` is nested,that's why it has access to `private` members of the parent type.If you make it like this:

```
class Base
{
   int i = 1;
}
public class SubDerived : Base
{
   public void f()
   {
        Console.WriteLine(base.i);
   }
}
```

You won't be able to access `i`.You need to make it `protected`.

Comment: so when derived class is nested in base class, private members are inherited?

Comment: yes, read more about nested types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

Comment: @tamazbagdavadze Private members are always inherited irrespective of nested class. Additionaly nested class makes it accessible for you.